# How to add new line in MemoEdit (DevExpress)

Tags: c#-4.0

```
int maxLength = 90;
var sb = new StringBuilder();
DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit edit = sender as DevExpress.XtraEditors.MemoEdit;
foreach(string str in edit.Lines) {
   if(str.Length > maxLength) {
      e.Cancel = true;
      sb.AppendLine(memoShipMark.Text);
      return;
   }
}
```

This not add new line it focus first line

Answer (score 0):

In C# `\n` is a new line syntax. It can use with built-in components in visual studio but can't use with devexpress's components.

After I search for a while, someone teach me I should use `\r\n` syntax and when I use. Oh! it's work with devexpress components.

Example

```
MemoEdit.Text = "data1: " + data1 + "\r\n" + "data2: " + data2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this line

```
sb.AppendLine(memoShipMark.Text);
```

to

```
sb.AppendLine($"{memoShipMark.Text}\r\n");
```

or you can use `Environment.NewLine` which is better for cross-platform programs as it will use the [proper newline character(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for the current operating system/character set.

```
sb.AppendLine(memoShipMark.Text + Environment.NewLine);
```